# Phrasing a Large(ish) text string in Lua

Tags: lua, tabletop-simulator

I am a hobbest modder for a game called TableTop Simulator that uses Lua.

I have a single string containing a list of data on multiple lines that represents a deck of cards.

```
Example:
2x Blackwood File Clerk
1x Patrol Wagon
3x Short Fuse
1x Adult Deep One
1x Deep One Assault
1x Shadowed Reef
3x Agoraphobia
```

What I need to do is get that string into a phrased format that I can use to then take the cards and the quantity out to build the decks.

I was thinking of trying to make some kind of table that looks like this..

```
deckList{}
   deckList[1].name = 'Blackwood File Clerk'
   deckList[1].quantity= 2
   deckList[2].name = 'Patrol Wagon'
   deckList[2].quantity= 1
```

etc etc....

then I can use the name string to find the matching card and then the quantity value to take that many copies of it.

The problem I have is that I do not know how to do this... I need to somehow separate each line and then pull out the value and stuff. I think as it is always 1,2,3 instead of cutting and being complex I can turn a line into '1x ', as removing that will leave 'name' perfectly for searching. Still I need to read each line and stuff as well.

Comment: For ideas, look into [`string.gmatch`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-string.gmatch)

Comment: Also, it is Lua (or lua), not LUA. Check https://www.lua.org/about.html

Answer (score 2):

```
local str = [[
2x Blackwood File Clerk
1x Patrol Wagon
3x Short Fuse
1x Adult Deep One
1x Deep One Assault
1x Shadowed Reef
3x Agoraphobia]]

local deckList = {}
for line in str:gmatch"[^\r\n]+" do
   local qty, name = line:match"^(%d+)x%s+(.-)%s*$"
   table.insert(deckList, {name = name, quantity = tonumber(qty)})
end
```